# Should I use @PostContruct or Context refresh event to connect to CTI server

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am developing a REST service which will connect to a CTI server through TCP and the connection will be kept opened until the my REST service is running.

Currently I am reading the server parameters from properties file and creating bean, after the bean is constructed, the server connection will be initiated using `@PostConstruct`. Is it good to use `@PostConstruct` for this scenario or should I use context refresh event.

I tested application using both `@PostConstruct` and context refresh, both are working good how ever I want to follow the best practices.

Note : I searched the forum and got some answers, but not related to my scenario

Comment: When you say until my REST service is running, does that mean until the server restarts again ?

Comment: If your connection initialization will depend something on the event of context which will trigger whenever context event dispatched then you should use context refresh event. Otherwise no point of use it!

Comment: @yaswanth yes I mean until the server restarts

Comment: @Zico no the connection is not depending the context, it depends on the bean(created from property file) and I think '@PostConstruct' will be called only once.

Comment: Yes @PostConstruct will be called once at bean creation time

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no difference. You have already tested that part. I think `@PostConstruct` makes more sense mainly because the connection you are creating is specific to this bean. Creating a new `ApplicationContextListener` wouldn't make much sense as the connection is not at a context level.